# How do you align flex items inside a css grid to its grid lines?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid, tailwind-css

So I made a layout using CSS Grid, and some elements inside the grid uses flexbox like article boxes and other one dimensional sections. How do I align this flex items to the main grid layout with a working responsive layout?

For a 12 column grid layout I tried using percentages (tailwind's `w-1/*` utilities) in the flexbox but can't manage to align them perfectly to the grid areas. Is it even possible? Or should I just use grid all through out?

Here's a sample illustration of my layout, first column is just there to show the 12 grid areas, second column is a layout using the said 12 column grid, and third column holds the flexbox container which I want to align (its boxes' edges) to the main grid.

[image]

Tailwindcss solution is preferred but not required.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.4/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container mx-auto">
  
  <div class="grid gap-4 grid-cols-12 h-40 my-5">
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
     <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
    
      <div class="col-start-2 col-span-5 bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      
      <div class="col-start-2 col-span-10 relative w-full flex flex-row h-5">
        <div class="bg-red-500 w-1/3 mr-4"></div>
        <div class="bg-yellow-300 w-1/3 mr-4"></div>
        <div class="bg-red-500 w-1/3"></div>
      </div>
  </div>

  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `div` has `w-full` class. `w-full` is `width: 100%`.

Then you have nested three nested `div's`:

```
<div class="col-start-2 col-span-10 relative w-full flex flex-row h-5">
    <div class="bg-red-500 w-1/3 mr-4"></div>
    <div class="bg-yellow-300 w-1/3 mr-4"></div>
    <div class="bg-red-500 w-1/3"></div>
</div>
```

So the above divs placed in `<div class="col-start-2 col-span-10 relative w-full flex flex-row h-5">` and they are aligned prefectly
according their parent.

So if you want to align these div's, then you need put then inside `grid`, not in `div`:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.4/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container mx-auto">
  
  <div class="grid gap-4 grid-cols-12 h-40 my-5">
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
     <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
    
      <div class="col-start-2 col-span-5 bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      
      <div class="col-start-2 col-span-4 bg-red-500">1</div>
      <div class="col-span-2 bg-yellow-300">2</div>
      <div class="col-span-2 bg-red-500">3</div>
  </div>

  
</div>
```

It can be seen that all nested `div's` are perfectly placed inside div:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.4/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container mx-auto">
  
  <div class="grid gap-4 grid-cols-12 h-40 my-5">
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
     <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
    
      <div class="col-start-2 col-span-5 bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      
      <div class="col-start-2 col-span-10 relative w-full flex flex-row h-5" style="overflow-y: auto; flex-direction: column;">
    <div class="bg-red-500 w-full mr-4">Flex 1</div>
    <div class="bg-yellow-300 w-full mr-4">Flex 2</div>
    <div class="bg-red-500 w-full">Flex 3</div>
  </div>
  </div>

  
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to have `display: flex` for nested items, then we can declare this class in outer container and put nested elements inside of it:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.4/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container mx-auto">
  
  <div class="grid gap-4 grid-cols-12 h-40 my-5">
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
     <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
    
      <div class="col-start-2 col-span-5 bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-green-300"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-300"></div>
      
      <div class="col-start-2 col-span-4 bg-red-500  
          w-full flex flex-row h-5">
    <div class="w-1/3">1</div>
    <div class="w-1/3">2</div>
    <div class="w-1/3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-span-2 bg-yellow-300 w-full flex flex-row h-5">
    <div class="w-1/3">1</div>
    <div class="w-1/3">2</div>
    <div class="w-1/3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-span-2 bg-red-500 w-full flex flex-row h-5">
    <div class="w-1/3">1</div>
    <div class="w-1/3">2</div>
    <div class="w-1/3">3</div>
  </div>
  </div>

  
</div>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

If you want responsive grid, you can use media query to gain it. Let me show an example:

```css
.main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 140px 180px 140px;
  grid-auto-rows: 30px;
  grid-column-gap: 7px;
}

.upper-main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 140px 180px 140px;
  grid-auto-rows: 30px;
  grid-column-gap: 7px;
}

.one {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.two {
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}

.three {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

@media ( max-width: 400px ) {
  .main-container {
    grid-template-columns: 140px 180px;
    grid-column-gap: 1px;
  }

   .upper-main-container {
    grid-template-columns: 107px 107px 107px;
    grid-auto-rows: 30px;
    grid-column-gap: 1px;
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class="upper-main-container">
   <div class="one">1</div>
   <div class="two">2</div>
   <div class="three">3</div>
 </div>
 <div class="main-container">
   <div class="one">1</div>
   <div class="two">2</div>
   <div class="three">3</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, your first code snippet is the layout that I want, but the third column does not use flex box. In your second one it has flex box, but the items are full width so I can't really see the alignment of its columns. To put it simply I want the layout of your first code snippet but using flex box items on the third row. Is it not possible so I have to always use grid to align the columns correctly?

Comment: @Jjj you can use `flex` like in the second example. However all nested elements `Flex 1`, `Flex 2` and `Flex 3` will be placed inside this div - `<div class="col-start-2 col-span-10 relative w-full flex flex-row h-5" style="overflow-y: auto; flex-direction: column;">`. Because of this these nested elements are aligned according `flex`, not `grid` and it is correct behavior because these three divs nested in `div` container which has `display: flex`

Comment: @Jjj it looks like I see your point. Please, see my updated answer. Now all nested items are aligned according outer container

Comment: Thank you, but the flex items are now surrounded with a grid item. In your example I want the red and yellow boxes to be flexbox items themselves (not flexbox containers). So just 3 flex items - red, yellow, red. And no flex items inside them.. 

Probably not possible, but I only want to use flexbox in the third row because I want it to be responsive and  wrap when the screen gets smaller. So for example if the screen is smaller the second red box gets into a new line.

Comment: @Jjj it looks like you want responsive grid. If yes, so you can use CSS plain `@media` query to have desired grid. Please, see my updated answer

Answer (score -3):

Based on your illustration it seems you are working with rows not columns. Columns are vertical and rows are horizontal.
Also with flex box there is a grow property that might help. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
You could also try adding a div around the whole thing, setting it’s display to flex and then you might be able to use the flex-end property to make the row you are using stretch to the end.

Comment: Anwser must be a definete solution. Your anwser would fit as a comment but not as an anwser. To fit an anwser it should contain mroe then just a link and some vague guesses. Preferably an anwser should contain a working code snippet showing that your solution would work. Also `flex-end` does not make flexitems stretch to the end. it starts placing them at the end (reverese placing). To make flexitems grow to the end, you would need flex-grow instead.